# VBA - create a condition based SQL query

Tags: sql, excel, vba, multiple-conditions

I'm quite new to VBA and I would like to find a simpler way to create a SQL query.
I have 4 comboboxes and the query depends on if they are filled or not. One of the combobox is linked to a userform with multiple checkboxes that would add to the query.

Here is the code I have at the moment and I want to increment the userform conditions:

```
If Sheets("Home Page").opecbbx.Value <> "" And Sheets("Home Page").wellchk.Value = False Then 'contractor only
        op = Sheets("Home Page").opecbbx.Value

                If Sheets("Home Page").sizcbbx.Value <> "" Then 'contractor and size
                    'Create SQL statement for filtering.
                    siz = Sheets("Home Page").sizcbbx.Value
                    SQL = "SELECT * FROM Filter Where contractor Like '%" & op & "%' And size_sec Like '%" & siz & "%';"

                Else

                    SQL = "SELECT * FROM Filter Where contractor Like '%" & op & "%';"

                End If

    ElseIf Sheets("Home Page").wellchk.Value = True And Sheets("Home Page").opecbbx.Value <> "" Then 'contractor and well
    op = Sheets("Home Page").opecbbx.Value

                If Sheets("Home Page").sizcbbx.Value <> "" Then 'contractor, size and well

                            siz = Sheets("Home Page").sizcbbx.Value
                            SQL = "SELECT * FROM Filter Where contractor Like '%" & op & "%' And size_sec Like '%" & siz & "%' And ID_NOC = '" & well & "';"

                Else

                    SQL = "SELECT * FROM Filter Where contractor Like '%" & op & "%' and ID_NOC='" & well & "';"

                End If

    ElseIf Sheets("Home Page").wellchk.Value = True Then

                If Sheets("Home Page").sizcbbx.Value <> "" Then 'size and well

                    siz = Sheets("Home Page").sizcbbx.Value
                    SQL = "SELECT * FROM Filter Where size_sec Like '%" & siz & "%' And ID_NOC = '" & well & "';"

                Else

                     SQL = "SELECT * FROM Filter Where ID_NOC='" & well & "';"

                End If

    ElseIf Sheets("Home Page").sizcbbx.Value <> "" And Sheets("Home Page").wellchk.Value = False And Sheets("Home Page").opecbbx.Value = "" Then 'size only

                siz = Sheets("Home Page").sizcbbx.Value
                SQL = "SELECT * FROM Filter Where size_sec Like '%" & siz & "%';"

    'Formation only
    ElseIf Sheets("Home Page").wellchk.Value = False And Sheets("Home Page").opecbbx.Value = "" And Sheets("Home Page").sizcbbx.Value = "" Then

                SQL = "SELECT * FROM Filter"

    End If
```

How can I do that without adding lots of new conditions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can give a general answer here which might require some massaging to get working in VBA.  You may use a flexible prepared statement like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Filter
WHERE
    (contractor LIKE ? OR contractor IS NULL) AND
    (size_sec LIKE ? OR size_sec IS NULL) AND
    (ID_NOC = ? OR ID_NOC IS NULL);
```

To each of the placeholders `?`, you would either bind the value from the combobox, if defined, or just bind `NULL` otherwise.  For example, for the `contractor` placeholder, you would bind `op` if defined, otherwise `NULL`.  The way this approach works is that if a given criteria be `NULL`, then it gets ignored.  So, if you only had one of the three values available from the combobox, then only it would be used to filter in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try it! However, I will add a 4th condition called `Tool` which can be, contain only one criteria or multiple criteria. Is it possible?

Comment: That is harder to swing, but yes it should be possible.